# Install AWS cli on lambda function with custom runtime

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I've created a lambda function with custom runtime (provided.al2023) but I don't have aws cli installed. How can I installed it?

apt and yum ins not installed.
dnf throws the following error: error: Failed to create: /var/cache/yum/metadata

I thought that AWS cli should be already installed on that machine but it doesn't.

Could anyone find a solution?

Comment: Lambda is not meant to provide a general purpose operating system.  Instead of invoking the aws cli, use the aws sdk for your chosen programming language.

Comment: @erik258 I see. But I'm using Bash scripts. How can I figure it out?

Comment: Since bash relies on a plethora of underlying operating system utilities, you'll probably have the best luck using docker to ship the lambda runtome environment.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html

Comment: @mgg Instead of running, lambda with container images, It will be better to use the AWS SDK and update the bash script to SDK commands.

Other solution I would recommend is using EC2 instance with aws-cli installed in them, and you can invoke SSM from Lamabda and execute your script in EC2 machine which is being invoked from Lambda.

Comment: Hii @mgg, you can refer this option:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69811739/aws-lambda-how-can-i-run-aws-cli-commands-in-lambda